# Read all data of MCP230XX at once

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have used a MCP203XX to have more inputs on my Raspberry. And my program reads all the inputs, but not all at the same time. How can I adjust my program so they are all read at the same time?
I know it's because of my If statements, but I don't know the correct way since I don't have that much experience in programming.

```
import smbus
import time
import snap7
import struct

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

DEVICE = 0x20 #Device adress (A0-A2)
IODIRA = 0x00 #Pin direction register
GPIOA = 0x12 #Register for inputs
IODIRB = 0x01
GPIOB = 0x13

#Set GPA pins as inputs
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,IODIRA,0xFF)
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,IODIRB,0xFF)


# connecting PLC
client = snap7.client.Client()
client.connect('192.168.5.2', 0, 1)
db_number = 109
start1 = 64
start2 = 65

#Loop until user presses CTRL-C
while True:

    #Read state of GPIOB register
    MySwitchB = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE,GPIOB)

    if MySwitchB & 0b00000001 == 0b00000001:
        in1 = 1
        print('Switch1 was pressed!')

    else:
        in1 = 0
        print('no1')

    if MySwitchB & 0b00000010 == 0b00000010:
        in2 = 1
        print('Switch2 was pressed!')

    else:
        in2 = 0
        print('no2')

    if MySwitchB & 0b00000100 == 0b00000100:
        in3 = 1
        print('Switch3 was pressed!')

    else:
        in3 = 0
        print('no3')

    if MySwitchB & 0b00001000 == 0b00001000:
        in4 = 1
        print('Switch4 was pressed!')

    else:
        in4 = 0
        print('no4')

    if MySwitchB & 0b00010000 == 0b00010000:
        in5 = 1
        print('Switch5 was pressed!')

    else:
        in5 = 0
        print('no5')

    if MySwitchB & 0b00100000 == 0b00100000:
        in6 = 1
        print('Switch6 was pressed!')

    else:
        in6 = 0
        print('no6')

    if MySwitchB & 0b01000000 == 0b01000000:
        in7 = 1
        print('Switch7 was pressed!')

    else:
        in7 = 0
        print('no7')

    if MySwitchB & 0b10000000 == 0b10000000:
        in8 = 1
        print('Switch8 was pressed!')

    else:
        in8 = 0
        print('no8')

    #Read state of GPIOA register
    MySwitchA = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE,GPIOA)

    if MySwitchA & 0b00000001 == 0b00000001:
        in9 = 1
        print('Switch9 was pressed!')

    else:
        in9 = 0
        print('no9')

    if MySwitchA & 0b00000010 == 0b00000010:
        in10 = 1
        print('Switch10 was pressed!')

    else:
        in10 = 0
        print('no10')

    if MySwitchA & 0b00000100 == 0b00000100:
        in11 = 1
        print('Switch11 was pressed!')

    else:
        in11 = 0
        print('no11')


    if MySwitchA & 0b00001000 == 0b00001000:
        in12 = 1
        print('Switch12 was pressed!')

    else:
        in12 = 0
        print('no12')

    if MySwitchA & 0b00010000 == 0b00010000:
        in13 = 1
        print('Switch13 was pressed!')

    else:
        in13 = 0
        print('no13')

    if MySwitchA &  0b00100000 == 0b00100000:
        in14 = 1
        print('Switch14 was pressed!')

    else:
        in14 = 0
        print('no14')

    if MySwitchA & 0b01000000 == 0b01000000:
        in15 = 1
        print('Switch15 was pressed!')

    else:
        in15 = 0
        print('no15')

    if MySwitchA & 0b10000000 == 0b10000000:
        in16 = 1
        print('Switch16 was pressed!')

    else:
        in16 = 0
        print('no16')

    # decimal value of 8 binairy bits 
    som1 = in1 +in2 * 2 ** 1 +in3 * 2 ** 2 +in4 * 2 ** 3 +in5 * 2 ** 4 +in6 * 2 ** 5 +in7 * 2 ** 6 +in8 * 2 ** 7
    som2 = in9  +in10 * 2 ** 1 +in11 * 2 ** 2 +in12 * 2 ** 3 +in13 * 2 ** 4 +in14 * 2 ** 5 +in15 * 2 ** 6 +in16 * 2 ** 7 

    test_byte = 1

    test_data1 = bytearray(test_byte)
    test_data2 = bytearray(test_byte)

    test_data1[0] = som1
    test_data2[0] = som2
    client.db_write(db_number, start1, test_data1)
    client.db_write(db_number, start2, test_data2)

    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, it does not read same time?

In a forever loop you read inputs once for two ports, here:

```
MySwitchB = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE,GPIOB)
MySwitchA = bus.read_byte_data(DEVICE,GPIOA)
```

it would be better to change your array of ifs into something like

```
byte1 = 0
byte2 = 0
for i in range(0, 7):
    byte1 += MySwitchA & (1 << i)
for i in range(0, 7):
    byte2 += MySwitchB & (1 << i)
```

Then, I have no clue what You are trying to do next with test_byte. Do you try to get byte representation of number in your som1 and som2 values?
You can do this using `chr(som1)` or in case of my example:

```
number_of_bytes = 2
test_data = bytearray(number_of_bytes)
test_data[0] = chr(byte1)
test_data[1] = chr(byte2)
```